# How do you programmatically set or handle an object's new transform position after a mecanim animation finishes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, mecanim

- So I have a bunch of mecanim animations.

I have tried various combinations with "Root Transform Position (XZ)" (e.g. Checked, unchecked, Orginal & Center of Mass & "Apply Root Motion")

The issue is, every combination fails in some regard.

- Note: My animation moves the character

Thus, I would like the GameObject to be exactly where it is after the animation completes.

However, if you uncheck "Root Transform Position (XZ)", regardless of the animator's "Apply Root Motion" being checked or not, the animation does not move the GameObject during the animation.

If you do check "Root Transform Position (XZ)", it moves the GameObject (as it should), but after the animation completes, it still exists in the original (starting) position.  (Which is bad and a false illusion.)

How do you fix this?  Or programmatically set the new position to where the animation ended the GameObject?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your character have a navmesh agent? it could be the agent is pushing it back to its original location

Comment: I'm not sure.  It does seem like in any case, it will end up back where it started.  I even tried intercepting (disabling) the animator before the animation completes, but there are still issues.

Comment: How can you not know if it has a navmesh agent?

Comment: I looked it up, my chars do not contain any NavMeshAgents.

Comment: When you say its still in its original position.. you mean it looks like theres a copy?